# Finding largest eigenvalue in sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using numpy and scipy. I have a large sparse matrix and I want to find the largest eigenvalue of the sparse matrix. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh` for symmetric sparse matrices passing `which="LM"`:

```
eigvals, eigvecs = eigsh(A, k=10, which='LM', sigma=1.)
```

[but you should definitely read the documentation.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html)

Comment: can one omit the eigvecs computation if they are not needed?

Comment: @AlexTwain yes, by passing `return_eigenvectors=False`, in this case you have to use `eigvals = eigsh(...)` instead

Comment: I don't really understand the use of sigma=1. here. I read the documentation, but is that really necessary?!

Comment: @AlexTwain What I've experienced is that the value for `sigma` can really change the algorithm's performance, for me it works fast with `sigma=1.`, perhaps another value will be better for your problem

Comment: but I found that I'm getting different results, by omiting or adding sigma!

Comment: @AlexTwain is your matrix symmetric?

Comment: Just to be clear, I hope you're not implying being `N X N` makes a matrix symmetric.