# Compute largest and smallest eigenvalue of real symmetric matrix

Tags: python, performance, matrix, eigenvalue

I am trying to work out the quickest way to *compute the largest and smallest eigenvalues of NxN real symmetric matrices* (where N is around 1000). This process has be repeated a large number of times so I need the whole thing to be as rapid as possible. At the moment the method I use is the following:

```
def return_max_min(C)
   egvs = np.linalg.eigvalsh(C)
   return min(egvs) , max(egvs)
```

Unfortunately, this is not very efficient.
In a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507707/finding-largest-eigenvalue-in-sparse-matrix) someone suggested the following solution:

```
 import scipy.sparse.linalg as sparlg

 max_egv = sparlg.eigsh(C, k=10, return_eigenvectors=False, which=('LM'), sigma=1.)
 min_egv = sparlg.eigsh(C, k=10, return_eigenvectors=False, which=('SM'), sigma=1.)
```

However, this somehow doesn't seem to be quicker than the first.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a limitation of in-built methods?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does the process have to be repeated with the same matrix? You can always just store the result once somewhere and use it again when needed.

Comment: No, the matrix changes every time, although they are all NxN real symmetric.